Database migrations in cache databases
I used to work with several types of databases (MySQL to MongoDB).
In every cases, I use to create migrations (cf revisions) of my database to make versions of it.
For this I usually write 'alembic code'.
I recently discovered DuckDB engine.
I was wondering (in my mind this is a good practice but I don't know if I can apply it here) if making version of the local duckdb database makes any sense or not.
I tried looking for article in that way but I cannot find any!
Thank you a lot for your future answers!

I'm not experienced with Alembic but let me try to help. DuckDB does not support versioned databases at the moment. Every DuckDB database is a single file, so you can store multiple databases by having multiple database files. Then, you can connect to these (multiple ones at the same time) using the ATTACH command. This way, you can access multiple versions at the same time by using e.g., SELECT * FROM version1.tbl, version2.tbl;.

Thank you a lot for your answer. I will check about think :)

DuckDB does not support versioned databases at the moment. However, every DuckDB database is a single file, so you can store multiple databases by having multiple database files. Then, you can connect to these (multiple ones at the same time) using the ATTACH command. This way, you can access multiple versions at the same time by using e.g.:
SELECT *
FROM version1.tbl, version2.tbl;

